# value of progressbar doesnt work

Tags: angularjs, progress-bar

theres my progress bar code:

```
<div class="col-sm-4" ng-repeat="var in payloadNbrMissionParStatut">
        <h4 class="no-margin">{{var.number}}</h4>
        <progressbar  value={{tom}} class="progress-xs no-radius no-margin" type={{gg}} ng-if="var.des=='Clos' ? gg='danger' : var.des=='En cours'? gg='warning' :gg='info' " ></progressbar>
                    {{var.des}}
</div>
```

the problem is in the value: when i populate it with static data it works good, but when i populate wit data come from the controller it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

`var` is a reserved JS keyword. As errors inside directive expressions are silent, you aren't seeing any alerts because it's simply being ignored. Change `var` to something else and it should work.